# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047 i just try whole day but nothing works

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

hi guys i'm new in python, i want to connect database oracle with python but i have a problem on this. can someone help me to fix this problem?

`import cx_Oracle`
`connection = cx_Oracle.connect("xxx/xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx:xxxx/xxxx")`

`cursor = connection.cursor()`
`cursor.execute(""" select * from all_transaction""")`
`for result in cursor:`
`print(result)`

The output is

**cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help.**

How can i fix this problem?

note: i've already install oracle client and cx_Oracle.

Comment: Is it possible you have downloaded as 32bit client (and thus the 64bit cannot be found?)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you follow the instructions (at the bottom of the looong page, Installation of ZIP files)? https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html Did you export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald i downloaded both 64 bit

Comment: @BjarteBrandt can u give me a guidence?

Comment: You need to show us exactly what you did.  What did you download?  Where did you put it?  Start by telling us what operating system you are on.

Comment: PS Please update your question with all the information; don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to the value 72. This will show all attempts to load the library and also give some indication of why they failed. Please ensure that you are using cx_Oracle 8 when you make this attempt.